# ViewPager: Adapter views not restoring when going back

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Here's my hierarchy:

```
CoordinatorLayout
- AppBarLayout
    - CollapsingToolbarLayout
- NestedScrollView
    - FrameLayout (contentFrame)
        - Container Fragment
            - ViewPager
                - Recycler(List) Fragment
                - Map Fragment
            - TabLayout
```

The Container Fragment shows a tabbed interface of two fragments: List and Map.  Location data is listed and mapped, respectively.  Selecting a location replaces the contentFrame fragment with a detail of the location data.

All of this is fine until I click the back button and return to the Container Fragment: the views that should be provided by the adapter are not restored and only the tabs are visible on the screen.  I've tried stepping through the lifecycles of every fragment involved and have read documentation until my eyes have gone crossed.  What could be the reason this is happening?

Comment: Is this all within one activity? My gut reaction is that your "by region" fragment's state is being lost when your "annbriar golf course" fragment is displayed (a fragment's instance state is only guaranteed to be saved when the activity's instance state is saved). But of course it will be hard to know for sure without seeing the code.

Comment: @BenP. Yes- it's all within one activity, using Fragments that are displayed within the contentFrame FrameLayout.

mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                                    .replace(R.id.contentFrame, fragment)
                                    .addToBackStack(null)
                                    .commit();

Comment: You can see from the screen title and the TabLayout that your transaction is successfully being popped off the back stack, which leads me to think that the problem is in how your ViewPager is being set up. Perhaps there's some initialization code that only runs the first time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are displaying a fragment within a fragment you should be using the child fragment manager. So you should be using the child fragment manager for your viewpager:

```
getChildFragmentManager()
```

instead of

```
getFragmentManager()
```

Are you doing that? hard to know without the code.

But sounds like it may be your problem

Comment: Aha! This definitely has something to do with it.  I was using getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().  I made the change to getChildFragmentManager() and now when I click back, it's crashing within the Map fragment's onCreateView method, but it does appear to have me moving in the right direction.